# Android scroll listView like Viber

Tags: android, listview

I just want to know how can I add to my listView or RecyclerView this effect to scroll and none item more like viber chat.

See the photos to know what i mean.
Before scroll this the end of chat:

[image]

Now scroll and the chat was ended and the emotion like spring:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is a class i wrote earlier
https://github.com/omiz/ZSwipeRefreshLayout/blob/master/ZSwipeRefreshLayout

to use it you simply need to add your list inside it like this

```
<ZSwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/main_recyclerView_days"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ZSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and in your code

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (ZSwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);

swipeRefreshLayout.setHeaderView(createHeaderView());

swipeRefreshLayout.setPushEnable(true);

swipeRefreshLayout.setPullEnable(true);

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnPullRefreshListener(this);
```

by the way this answer is to make a ListView or RecyclerView bounce like iOS effect

Comment: please let me know if you need any further help

Comment: did its work for GrideView and `createHeaderView()` show error i am on fragment now

Comment: i only tested it in ListView and RecyclerView

Comment: createHeaderView() is any view of your choice you can add an empty view